# Python: Parse json data from a list with the same name

Tags: python, json, parsing

So I have the next json and I want to get just the github link and the twitter one without taking the foursquare and gravatar one.

Also this in not all, sometimes the json data can change and if doesn't find a foursquare url, github will become first and twitter the second one. With the other ones (github or twitter) will be the same.

How can I get the github and twitter url if they are not in the same position as in this json?

```
{ "socialProfiles": [
    {
        "type": "foursquare",
        "typeId": "foursquare",
        "typeName": "Foursquare",
        "url": "https://foursquare.com/user/somerandomuser",
        "id": "554225246246"
    },
    {
        "type": "github",
        "typeId": "github",
        "typeName": "Github",
        "url": "https://github.com/somerandomuser",
        "username": "somerandomuser"
    },
    {
        "type": "gravatar",
        "typeId": "gravatar",
        "typeName": "Gravatar",
        "url": "https://gravatar.com/somerandomuser",
        "username": "somerandomuser",
        "id": "132341667"
    },
    {
        "bio": " This is a bio of a random user",
        "followers": 543,
        "following": 222,
        "type": "twitter",
        "typeId": "twitter",
        "typeName": "Twitter",
        "url": "https://twitter.com/somerandomuser",
        "username": "somerandomuser",
        "id": "41414515335"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `dict comprehension` to create another `dict` only with the urls that you need, in this case `twitter` and `github`

```
search = ['github', 'twitter']

urls = {dct['type']: dct['url'] for dct in data.get('socialProfiles', []) if dct['type'] in search}
print(urls)
```

**Output**

```
{
    'github': 'https://github.com/somerandomuser',
    'twitter': 'https://twitter.com/somerandomuser'
}
```

And after that you can get the `url` that you need.

```
print(urls['github'])

# Output
# https://github.com/somerandomuser
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me a lot :)

Comment: if you are nice enough, could you help me to combine that with .get() so I will get none if there's no socualProfiles ? I know I could use try but I would love to use .get even if it's slower. ^^

Comment: i update my answer, with `None` it don't work, because `None` is not iterable , and it will throw an error, but you can get the empty dict if is not `socialProfiles`,

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple iteration.

**Ex:**

```
checkList = ["twitter", "github"]
for i in data["socialProfiles"]:
    if i["typeId"] in checkList:    #Check if typeid is in your check-list
        print(i["url"])
```

**Output:**

```
https://github.com/somerandomuser
https://twitter.com/somerandomuser
```

- `data` is your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for social_profile in data["socialProfiles"]:
    for link in social_profile:
        if link['typeId'] == "twitter" or link['typeId'] == "github":
           print (link["url"])
```

Comment: REVIEW: It's much better to provide description in the answer and not just code.